# Why there are no border set phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', "No");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', "Roc No");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', "Company Name");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', "Address");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', "Phone No");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1', "Fax No");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G1', "Email");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H1', "Preqpoint");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I1', "Preqstatus");

$styleArray = array('borders' => array('allborders' => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,'color' => array('argb' => '000000'),),),);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:I1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:I1')->getBorders()->getAllBorders()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN)->getColor()->setRGB('000000');
```

I try to add border around the cell with this code but i dont know why it is not working and i am bad in english

Comment: change argb to rgb then set 000000 to something like 808080. because 000000 is transparent color

Comment: not working and i also change the font but also not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764155/phpexcel-how-to-apply-styles-and-set-cell-width-and-cell-height-to-cell-generate check this maybe it will help.