# Codeigniter and PHPExcel make cells auto width

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I am exporting a list from my database using PHPExcel.

But the cells are not evenly spaced as shown in image.

> Question: How can I make sure that each cell is automatically evenly spaced in PHPExcel

I have tried the answers here but not work properly

[PHPExcel How to apply styles and set cell width and cell height to cell generated dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764155/phpexcel-how-to-apply-styles-and-set-cell-width-and-cell-height-to-cell-generate)

[image]

Controller Code

```
<?php

class Events extends MX_Controller {

    private $error = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function generate_excel() {

        $query = $this->db->get('event');
        $excelresults = $query->result_array();

        require (APPPATH . 'third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
        require (APPPATH . 'third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');

        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("");

        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("");

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A1", 'Event');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B1", 'Event Title');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("C1", 'Event Date');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("D1", 'Event Start Time');

        $excelrow = 2;

        foreach ($excelresults as $excelresult => $excelvalue) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event_title']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("C" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event_date']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("D" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event_start_time']);

            $excelrow++;
        }

        $filename = 'Bowling-Events-For ' . date('Y') . '.xlsx';
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Riwaka Bowling Club Events");

        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' .$filename. '"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $Writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $Writer->save('php://output');

        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solved found solution

Did some more google searching from answer here 
[PHPExcel auto size column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761897/phpexcel-auto-size-column-width)

```
foreach (range('A', $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn()) as $col) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension($col)
            ->setAutoSize(true);
    }
```

[image]